Error opening radeonsi and swrast drivers on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
I am using a dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. When running the code, the program displays an error:
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open radeonsi: /usr/lib/dri/radeonsi_dri.so: 
Cannot open shared object file: No file or folder of that name (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64- linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)  
libGL error: failed to load driver: radeonsi  
libGL error: MESA-LOADER: failed to open swrast: /usr/lib/dri/swrast_dri.so:  
Cannot open shared object file:    
No file or folder of that name (search paths /usr/lib/x86_64- linux-gnu/dri:\$${ORIGIN}/dri:/usr/lib/dri, suffix _dri)   
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast     

I have an HP ProBook 445-G7 with processor AMD Ryzen 5 with Radeon graphics x6 and using a dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.04.
